# Retirar tag <a> usando php e deixar somente texto <td>

Tags: php, html

Estou utilizando o PHPMailer para fazer envios de emails, porem no corpo do email tem um campo (endereco) que está chegando como link (para o maps) para o destinatário.

Já utilizei o strip_tags() mas não resolveu. Localmente funciona, porem quando testo online não funciona.

Código:

```
 $end = $_POST['endereco'];
 $enderecoFormatado= strip_tags($end, '<a>');

 $corpo = "<h1><table>       
    <tr>
      <td>Endereco: </td>
      <td>
        $enderecoFormatado
      </td>
    </tr>        
  </table>";


 $corpo = utf8_decode($corpo);
 $mail->msgHTML($corpo);
```

Comment: Pode ser que o cliente de email detecte URLs e os transformam em links.

Comment: E não tem como eu restringir isso? (Mexendo no meu código é claro), de alguma forma que só chegue o texto para ele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em geral não tem como evitar isso, porque o cliente de email adiciona links automaticamente quando encontra URLs válidas no corpo da mensagem.

Porém, existe um truque que *engana* o sistema e não adiciona os links. Basta colocar os endereços (URLs) entre as tags `<a></a>` (sem `href` nem nada, apenas `<a>`). Exemplo:

```
<a>http://www.site.com</a>
```

Inclusive funciona com endereços de email:

```
<a>email@site.com</a>
```

> **Obs.:** Testado no Gmail e Hotmail com sucesso.

Comment: Fiz vários testes e não veio como link. Vc testou no Gmail?

Comment: Nos meus dominios

Comment: Pois é, a resposta é que não tem como evitar isso. Só apresentei uma forma que funciona pelo menos no Gmail e Hotmail.

Comment: Pois é, que eu saiba,  somente em `$mail->IsHTML(false);` daí vai tudo como texto

Comment: Poderia ser, mas só no caso de ser texto puro.

Comment: Deu certo aqui cara, muito obrigado pela dica.